# How to store browser's network information into database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to store browser's network information into database. How can I do this in ruby on rails?
[image]
Network information like - All individual request that comes in network that I want to store into database.

Is there any gems or any api that I can get this information and store into database?

Thanks

Comment: See this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-remote_ip

Comment: You decide which data from the request you want to save, make those table/fields in the database, and save the request data into them via a `before_filter`.  If that isn't what you meant, then please be more specific in your question.

Comment: You should probably be using a tool like https://calibreapp.com/ or New Relic for this.